# compare two string variables to determine if it is the same

Tags: powershell

I have `$loopback_address` is 192.168.1.1/24 and `$source_address` is 192.168.1.1.  I wrote a PowerShell script to split the loopback address and compare it to the source address as below:

```
$Loopback_ip = ($loopback_address -split '/')
# so my $loopback_ip[0] is now equal to 192.168.1.1 which should be the
# same as the source_address.
if ($loopback_ip[0] -eq $source_address) {
    Write-Host "same"
} else {
    Write-Host "different"
}
```

The result should be "same" but it is "different".

Comment: Please show the output of `$loopback_ip[0] | %{"-$_-"}` and `$source_address | %{"-$_-"}`.

Comment: Is one a string, and is one a double?

Comment: Ansgar, not sure what you wanted me to do with $loopback_ip[0] | %{"-$_-"} and $source_address | %{"-$_-"}???   yes the output of $loopback_ip[0] is 192.168.1.1

Comment: medicine_man , they are two separate string

Comment: I think that those strings contain "CR" characters etc. Try `$loopback_ip[0].Trim() -eq $source_address.Trim()`.

Comment: You could modify your Write-Host to output all the data to make sure your two strings are equal (we don't know where $loopback_address and $source_address comes from):  `Write-Host "different: loopback=$loopback_ip[0]-source=$source_address"`. Please copy paste the exact output from this write-host.